# Wordpress duplicator archive.zip uploads then vanishes from server

Tags: wordpress, plugins, filezilla

I've tried to migrate my wordpress website from localhost to byethost32 using duplicator plugin, but I can only transfer the installer.php file. When I upload the packaged wp zip it shows that the upload is completed, but after refreshing it disappears. I've also tried uploading the zip file via cPanel's online file manager, but when I press the green check mark to continue, cPanel asks me to login and brings me back to the start without adding the archive.

Comment: Is the file too big for this host? Does the host have any content restrictions on what you can upload? Is it a virus checker deleting it? The fact your login session is broken by the upload sounds significant.

Comment: The archive is 57mb. The upload restrictions are listed

Comment: Restrictions:
The maximum size of one file is restricted by net2ftp to 9.54 MB and by PHP to 10 MB
The maximum execution time is 800 seconds
The FTP transfer mode (ASCII or BINARY) will be automatically determined, based on the filename extension
If the destination file already exists, it will be overwritten